# How to handle step definition method when i am passing vertical structured feature file

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, pageobjects

I have feature file mentioned below, I need to verify same using step definition as generic method so that it will be reusable.

```
| FieldName     | IsFieldMandatory | IsFieldEnabled | ErrorMessage              | ControlType |
| first name:   | Mandatory        | Enabled        | enter a valid first name  | TexBox      |
| second name:  | Mandatory        | Enabled        | enter a valid second name | TexBox      |
| account name: | Mandatory        | Enabled        | enter a valid account     | TexBox      |
| broker name:  | Mandatory        | Enabled        | enter a valid broker      | TexBox      |
```

And step definition is as below which uses each element Id string every time which is hardcoded in string array.

can i make this generic by only using feature file data without Id string being called to component file

```
public void PageContainsTheFollowingFieldsAsDefault(IList<ModelData> inputData)
    {
        foreach (int i=0;i<inputData.count();i++)
        {               string[] elementIdArray = {ContactFnameId, ContactSurnameId,ContactEmailId, AccountnameId};
            componentclass _control = new componentclass(elementIdArray[i],_webDriver)

                Assert.AreEqual(inputData[i].FieldName, _control.LabelText());
                Assert.AreEqual(GenericHelper.IsRequiredToBoolean(inputData[i].IsFieldMandatory), _control.MandatoryFieldCheck());
                Assert.AreEqual(GenericHelper.StringToBoolean(inputData[i].IsFieldEnabled), _control.IsEnabled());
                //As account Name doesn't have any error message validation
                if (inputData[i].FieldName != "Accountant name:")
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(inputData[i].FieldErrorMessage, _control.ValidateErrorMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to make more generic? Which element Id do you mean?

Comment: Hi Andreas,

What i mean is i am passing element string everytime when loop increases.
Means for i=1 contactFnameId,i=1 Contact surname,i=2 contactemailaddress and  i=3 accountname to component class( componentclass ) where element id will be initiated respective to it with webdriver.

can i avoid passing this into component class from stepdefiniton